Filtering Down by Custom Field
I am trying to filter down through our member database by current members and a Provider Address (in the form it reads "Find a Provider (1)) and not all members have added this address. I have tried titling the Address, filtering down by Address Name, and going through all the Administrator sections to see if I could find any hidden fields or checkboxes, etc.

Can you pls expand on your question. I don't quite follow. If you are trying to build a report/search for Members who have/have not provided a 'provider address' then you might want to explore SearchKit
